# How to generate 1,2,3,... sequence in Excel with each member repeated Ntimes

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's consider a sequence: 1,2,3,4,5.... That is obviously easy to create in Excel. But how would you create a derived sequence, where each of the member of the original sequence is there N-times in a row?

For N=3
1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,... etc.

I have ended up copying column of 1s with paste special add function sliding it N rows down every round. That is however far from good solution.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Is this in rows or columns?

Comment: in columns, but since we can transpose at any time - does it matter?

Comment: Depends if you are using the row function.....

Comment: @NeverStopLearning If you're using certain functions that do maths based on the size of a range, it can matter. If you use a function that relies on vertical arrangement, then transpose to horizontal, you will have undesirable results. A workaround is to Copy, then Paste Values before you transpose, but it's better to use the right formula the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution for this is to use a regular Excel formula.

If you're starting at A1, drop this formula in and then copy it down:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROWS(A$1:A1)/3,0)
```

**ROUNDUP** rounds a number up to *n* decimal places. In this case, *n* is set to 0 so Excel will round up to the nearest whole number.

**ROWS** counts the number of rows in a range. Adjust the range reference according to your starting location. When you copy/paste, Excel will handle adjustments for the other cells.

Note: The dollar sign here is *important*. It locks the reference for the start of the range so that it will *always* be in the starting row of your range, (or, more properly, the row of the first cell you drop the formula in - so start with this in the first row of your range) no matter how you copy/paste the formula. Without this, your formula will break when you copy it down. So, change the letters and numbers according to where your first cell will be, but leave that dollar sign there.

[image]

**/3** is there to divide the ROWS count by three. Since this is inside the ROUNDUP function, and that's set to 0 decimal places, all results will be rounded up to the nearest whole number. Once the formula is filled down the rest of the column, this will result in every number repeating 3 times. To get a different repetition rate, change 3 to a different number.

---

If you're looking to do this *across* a *row*, instead of *down* a *column* (e.g.: in A1, B1, C1,... instead of A1, A2, A3,...) you'll need to use the COLUMNS function instead of ROWS, and adjust the range reference so that the start column gets locked instead of the start row.

Example:

```
=ROUNDUP(COLUMNS($A1:A1)/3,0)
```

---

For a formula that will work in a row *or* column layout, you could use something like the one below, but it's better to just choose one of the above according to which layout you're actually using. This will also produce likely-undesirable results if your range spans multiple rows *and* multiple columns.

```
=ROUNDUP(COLUMNS($A1:A1)*ROWS(A$1:A1)/3,0)
```

---

For something that's non-sequential, and/or non-numeric, you'll want to set aside a range to be used as your source list. Let's say your list of source values is in column B, starting at B1. For that, to repeat the values 3 times each in Column A, you'd use this in A1 and copy down:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",ROUNDUP(ROWS(A$1:A1)/3,0)))
```

Note: This will not adjust for movement of the source column. You'll have to manually fix the formula, changing `"B"` to match the new location, if the source column is moved. If your source data starts in a row other than row 1, you'll need to tweak the formula a bit to add in the offset.

---

If you want to be able to adjust the repetition rate, use a reference cell for the divisor. Example below starts with the previous formula, and assumes the divisor will be in C1.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",ROUNDUP(ROWS(A$1:A1)/C1,0)))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest, however user wants columns, I was waiting on the answer to my comment before posting

Comment: @BobVale Threw in something for that, too. Thanks.

Comment: ...and one more catch-all. I'm a bit disappointed that there isn't a CELLS function to tally up a whole range - the Microsoft article I found via Google said to do ROWS\*COLUMNS.

Comment: This solution generates a unique column of values without considering an input series. Isn't the question, given a particular series, generate a derived series? For example, if the input series is not consecutive and sequential (ex: 1, 3, 2, etc) this solution fails.

Comment: @jdh The title and body of the question very specifically call out a sequence of natural numbers, in ascending order, starting with 1. Though some generalized verbiage is indeed used in the body, there is no clear indication that the OP is asking for a solution that can be generalized to fit any sequence in any order. However, with the addition of some other functions, the same logic which is used in my solution would still be useful to solve the generalized problem also.

Comment: Interesting that the vague description of this question has two different interpretations. I do not see the specification "ascending order" in the title or text. Instead, I see the word "sequence" and a simple example, that just happens to be in ascending order, but the title and description imply to me, that a sequence is a list of numbers in any order, ascending, descending or mixed. But in any case, this formula solution still does not reference the input sequence (except for manually typing in the seed value). Since the questioner doesn't give specs, multiple solutions could be valid.

Comment: @jdh As it is, the solution here only addresses an increasing sequence of whole numbers. It can be trivially adjusted to change the starting number. Additional functions, and supporting cells, would be needed to work with other sequences or different sorting of the sequence. However, the same logic (counting rows and dividing by the repetition rate) would still be at the core.

Comment: If you are using a source sequence and just repeating each number this solution still works perfectly, you simply use the offset function with the start of the source sequence and then the result of this solution in either the rows or columns. You'd actually either need to subtract one or start one before the start sequence to make it work

Comment: @BobVale I was thinking something more along the lines of using `INDIRECT` & `CONCATENATE`.

Comment: This indeed solves what I had in mind. Thanks a lot for this creative solution. Sorry if I made some room for alternative interpretation(s). After reading through the problem description again you are right, it can be taken as that we have some series already and we want to replicate each member Ntimes - a way more difficult problem imo.

Comment: Quite useful especially second one works for both Row & Column ,, +10 ☺

Answer (score 1):

One I found worked well for dynamic arrays:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(count*repeats,,1,1/repeats),0)
```

e.g. for count=2, with n=3 repeats

```
=ROUNDDOWN(SEQUENCE(6,,1,1/3),0)
```

Produces:

```
1,1,1,2,2,2
```

Answer (score 0):

To be flexible and re-useable for other situations (including features like putting the results in rows or columns, different workbooks etc) - the best approach is to use Excel's Macro language (VBA).
To quickly get going, you can record the approximate steps you want to automate in a macro and then edit that macro to fine tune and customize. For example, here's some vba code to triplicate each cell of the first column into the third column:

```
Sub triplicate()

iDestCol = 3
nCopy = 3
rowEnd = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
nIndex = 0
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To rowEnd
    For j = 1 To nCopy
        Cells((nIndex + j), iDestCol) = Cells(i, 1)
    Next j
    nIndex = nIndex + nCopy

Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Downside is that if you've got this for one of your rows or columns  and you insert a row in the middle you have to rerun the macro, whereas a formula based solution would just update

Comment: Macros can be written as add-in and then used as a custom formula, so that if the input parameter's value changes, the macro (aka addin formula) is automatically re-evaluated. In this case, the input series' location would be a parameter to triplicate(). For something simple like this, the effort for writing handling the addin protocol outweighs just manually re-running a macro.

Comment: Thanks, this answers the alternative interpretation. I know that with macros you can do whatever you want, but I was really interested in non-macro formula based solution. Sorry about that, I will explicitly mention that in the description next time.